# Huggingface load_dataset raises NonMatchingSplitsSizesError(str(bad_splits))

Tags: huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I used some dataset about a month ago and everything worked just fine when I ran

```
dataset = load_dataset('adversarial_qa', 'adversarialQA')
```

But now when I run it I get

```
  File "/projects/my_username/software/anaconda/envs/context/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1782, in load_dataset
    builder_instance.download_and_prepare(
  File "/projects/my_username/software/anaconda/envs/context/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 872, in download_and_prepare
    self._download_and_prepare(
  File "/projects/my_username/software/anaconda/envs/context/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 985, in _download_and_prepare
    verify_splits(self.info.splits, split_dict)
  File "/projects/my_username/software/anaconda/envs/context/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/utils/info_utils.py", line 100, in verify_splits
    raise NonMatchingSplitsSizesError(str(bad_splits))
datasets.utils.info_utils.NonMatchingSplitsSizesError: [{'expected': SplitInfo(name='train', num_bytes=27858686, num_examples=30000, shard_lengths=None, dataset_name=None), 'recorded': SplitInfo(name='tra
in', num_bytes=55764872, num_examples=60000, shard_lengths=None, dataset_name='parquet')}, {'expected': SplitInfo(name='validation', num_bytes=2757092, num_examples=3000, shard_lengths=None, dataset_name=
None), 'recorded': SplitInfo(name='validation', num_bytes=5518934, num_examples=6000, shard_lengths=None, dataset_name='parquet')}, {'expected': SplitInfo(name='test', num_bytes=2919479, num_examples=3000
, shard_lengths=None, dataset_name=None), 'recorded': SplitInfo(name='test', num_bytes=5842958, num_examples=6000, shard_lengths=None, dataset_name='parquet')}]
```

I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825418/nonmatchingsplitssizeserror-loading-huggingface-bookcorpus) that had a similar issue, but the dataset they used is no longer publicly available which was their issue and not mine. I found [this](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/nonmatchingsplitssizeserror/30033/1) similar question on the huggingface blog, which suggested:

1. Running the `load_dataset` with `download_mode="reuse_cache_if_exists"` -- resulted in the same error
2. Running the `load_dataset` with `ignore_verifications=True` -- resulted in `ValueError: 'none' is not a valid VerificationMode`
3. Running the `load_dataset` with `download_mode=“force_redownload”` -- resulted in the same error.

The accepted answer mentioned:

```
 To (re)compute these numbers automatically and dump them to a README.md file, one should run datasets-cli test your_dataset --save_info. And as it’s done manually, it depends on datasets’ authors if they update and push this info or not as it’s not required.
```

I deleted the `readme.md` file under the `cache` folder, but I still get the error.

I also tried going to the directory where I save the dataset and run
`datasets-cli test adversarial_qa --save_info`. Still get the same error.

**Update:**

The only thing that worked was downloading the parquet files manually from huggingface and running

```
dataset = load_dataset("parquet", data_files={'train': 'train.parquet', 'test': 'test.parquet'})
```

However, there has to be a better method to clear the cache or fix this...

Answer (score 0):

Got `NotImplementedError: Loading a dataset cached in a LocalFileSystem is not supported` even after downloading the parquet files. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77433096/notimplementederror-loading-a-dataset-cached-in-a-localfilesystem-is-not-suppor) helped.

`pip install -U datasets` solved the issue.